# How to replace the values of 1's and 0's of various column into a single column of a data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The 0's and 1's need to be transposed to there appropriate headers in python.
How can I achieve this and get the column final_list?[image: columns for different verticals]

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. Also - don't post images, please post it in writing format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is always only one `1` per rows use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0],
                   'b':[1,0,0],
                   'c':[0,0,1]})

df['Final'] = df.dot(df.columns)
print (df)
   a  b  c Final
0  0  1  0     b
1  1  0  0     a
2  0  0  1     c
```

If possible multiple `1` also add separator and then remove it by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) from output `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0],
                   'b':[1,1,0],
                   'c':[1,1,1]})

df['Final'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df)
   a  b  c  Final
0  0  1  1    b,c
1  1  1  1  a,b,c
2  0  0  1      c
```